# Second Vagrant Site Returns Empty Response

Tags: vagrant, homestead

I have a vagrant/homestead setup with two sites.

The first one works as expected, but when I started up the server today the second one is just returning a 200 status with no body:

[image]

My Homestead file is as follows

```
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
  - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
  - map: ~/code
    to: /home/vagrant/code

sites:
  - map: site1.test
    to: /home/vagrant/code/site1-backend/public

  - map: site2.test
    to: /home/vagrant/code/site2-backend/public


    databases:
        - dbname
```

My hosts file is

```
192.168.10.10   site1.test
192.168.10.10   site2.test
```

## Notes / Things I've Tried

- If I stop the vagrant I no longer get the 200 response so it is definitely connecting to it
- Any URL I go to at `site2.test` returns the empty 200 result
- Going to site3.test does not connect
- I am using Laravel in both projects, but there is no recent output in the Laravel logs
- On Vagrant `/var/log/nginx/site2.test-error.log` is empty as is `/var/log/nginx/error.log`
- Both projects have identical .htaccess files
- Both projects have `vagrant` as the owner for all files

I have run

```
> vagrant destroy && vagrant up
```

To no avail.

I'm not sure how to further debug this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be an error in my Laravel `.env` file

Changing

```
APP_NAME=App Name
```

to

```
APP_NAME="App Name"
```

Fixed it. I was unable to find any logging to this effect and worked it by comparing my setup with my live server.